# Change font for the file

Tags: emacs

I have a line in my .emacs which set a default font:

```
(set-default-font "Monaco-10")
```

It works fine for me, but I need two exceptions:

1. I need to change default font for a one file, for example ~/some. How can I do it?
2. I need to change default fonr for a gnux (M-x gnus). How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the variable `` `face-remapping-alist' ``.  For example, you can have something like this:

```
(add-hook 'find-file-hook
          (lambda ()
            (if (equal "~/some" (abbreviate-file-name (buffer-file-name)))
              (set (make-local-variable 'face-remapping-alist)
                   '((default :family "DejaVu Serif"))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

In Emacs files are represented in buffers - you don't change the font of the file, but that of the buffer. Shift-LeftClick in a buffer and you'll get a font dialog. In it you should select:

```
Change Buffer Font...
```

You might take a look at the code this command is bound to and use it for your needs.

Comment: I need to change the font automatically. Something like: if(openfilename = '~/some') (set-default-font "...").